# Get covariance from log-density function

Tags: st.statistics, random-functions

**Problem**
Given a following log-density function
$$ \ln p(y| a, b) = a \cdot g(y) + b \cdot h(y) + k(a,b)$$
where $g(y), h(y), k(a,b)$ are difined function and $a,b$ are parameters.
Find $\Bbb Cov( g(Y), h(Y))$ using $k(a,b)$.

**My try**
I believe that it got something to do with the score function and Fisher information. We basically can calculate the  Fisher information using two methods:

1. $\Bbb Var[(\ln p(y| a, b))'']$
2. $\Bbb -E[(\ln p(y| a, b))']$

These are derivatives.
My idea is to use both of these definitions and to make them equal. Since we have two parameters, I assume that it's a vector case.
Fisher information using (1):
$$\begin{bmatrix}
\Bbb Var( g(Y))\\
\Bbb Var( h(Y))
\end{bmatrix}$$
And Fisher infomration using (2)
$$\begin{bmatrix}
k_a''\\
k_b''
\end{bmatrix}$$
Even though I've found each of the variances, I have them separately and don't know how to get to the covariance.